# Is making \cite into a \footnote possible in ConTeXt mkiv

Tags: bibliographies, context

After examining "Bibliographies the Context way" I found that there is no response there to the question of how to make `\cite` work as `\foonote`. `\placelistofpublications` lines up `\cite` entries according to the criteria and style, whereas `\setupfootnotes[location=text]` and `\placefootnotes` makes footnotes after the chapter, but not the `\cite` entries. I understand it is all very raw, but at the same time, all points out there is some kind of setting which may allow one to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve.  It is possible to just wrap `\cite` into `\footnote`.

```
\usebtxdataset[mkiv-publications.bib]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]

\starttext

This is a footnote \footnote{\cite[authornum][article]}

\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! The "good old days" from before biblatex being very long ago I forgot one can do this. This solves it.